# get_the_author_meta( ) not fetching the user meta?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have this code to add some social media links

[image]

put when i go to the database to see the new user mata like 'twitter' i dont fint the new meta !!!
[image]

and whe`get_the_author_meta('twitter')` i get nothing !!

Comment: You need to use ```add_user_meta()``` first before you can update it.  So you're trying to update meta that does not yet exist.

Comment: @DubVader `update_user_meta()` calls through to `update_metadata()` which handles scenarios where the option does not yet exist (and where the option exists with an empty existing value) just fine.

Comment: Yep, you're right.

Comment: Please, don't post a screen capture of your code ... it makes it difficult for us to actually test it (_insert "ain't nobody got time to type all that" meme here_). Please edit your question to include your code as actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Your meta do not exist in your database so you need to put condition first to check whether your meta exist of not.

If it doesn't exist, use add_user_meta method like:

```
if(!empty(get_user_meta($user_id, 'twitter_meta'))) {
    add_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)
} else {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)
}
```

Try this one.